# [Bash][quotes] Unexpected shell output

Tags: bash, shell

The unexpected behaviour is the output in the shell when using double qoutes or not, i.e:

```
shell>: echo $var
Row1 This is the first Row2 This is the second Row3 This is the third

shell>: echo "$var"
Row1 This is the first 
Row2 This is the second 
Row3 This is the third
```

The amazing part is that the words Rown have a colored background, and this color is visible in both cases. The questions is the following:

¿If both things (color and \n) are escape commands, why the color is present in both cats and the escape line only in the second one?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure it's `cat` and not `echo`?

Comment: devnull, I see the effect, what is doing bash in a different way than other to have this behaviour?